# How to interpret python source string as a real string?

Tags: python

See this code:

```
my_src_str = '"""hello"""'

my_real_str = get_real_string_from_python_src_string(my_src_str)
```

In this case, `my_src_str` is a string representation in python source code format. I want to interpret it as a real python string. Here I want to get `hello` to `my_real_str`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> my_src_str = '"""hello"""'
>>> ast.literal_eval(my_src_str)
'hello'
```